# There are 40 mystery packs, you take out 4 at a time and are chasing one main prize that is $1000.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The main prize is 100% contained in one of the 40 packs. What are the odds of hitting said prize within the first 4 packs chosen out of the 40 packs? Is it said that you have 10% or is it said that you roughly have 2.5% per pack… Thank you, silly question but would like clarity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you know that the main prize is contained in one of the 40 packs?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Yes!

Comment: Then your attempt is correct (assuming a uniform distribution of the main prize)

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenjaminWang